# Expose date filter in views

Tags: views

So, what I want is a dropdown to filter news by months, the select box is like that(months are grouped by years):

```
- All
-- 2013
--- Jan
--- Feb
--- Mar
--- ...
-- 2012
--- Jan
--- Feb
--- Mar
```

How I can do that ?

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create groups for these results:

you want to group the results by Year and Month, so you need to add two fields:

[image]

**First field for group by Year [Content: Post date]:**

[image]

**Second field for group by Month [Content: Post date]:**

[image]

**Add filters and sort criteria:**

[image]

**Choose format settings:**

[image]

**Group yearly results:**

[image]

**Group monthly results:**

[image]

**That's it!**

Your results:

```
- 2013
-- Jan
--- tilte #1
--- ...
-- Feb
--- title #4
--- ...
--- Mar
--- title #6
--- ...
```

Comment: I want it to be a contextual filter to filter content ? not as a display of views

Comment: As I know you can't group your results with contextual filter. There is no this kind of option there. With the contextual filter you can only filter them.

Comment: Okey, you are right, but what u are doing here is note an exposed filter ? it's just grouping the output of views ?

Comment: Yes, it's just grouping the output of views. There is no contextual filters in use. With contextual filters you can display your news filterd by date, but do not group them. Grouping requires a filter for each group and option to render them as a groups and exclude the results from display within these groups.